# Build path issue with CSipSimple

Tags: android, build-process, dex, csip-simple

I know that this is a popular question in stackoverflow but I couldn't find a good solution for this issue.

I'm developing a SIP app for android and I'm using the CSipSimple project as a library (this project is also using actionbarsherlock as a library) until now I never had any problems when I runned my SIP app on an external device, but now I'm stucked with this message from the console:

```
[2013-03-28 15:24:49 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr;
[2013-03-28 15:24:49 - GoldenCallCSIP] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr;
```

I guess that might be a build path issue but I can't delete the concerned jars in the Android Dependencies virtual folder, more precisely due to the actionbarsherlock jar file which is in the Android Dependencies of the CSipSimple library I'm using and in my main project.

Any ideas about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it,

Clean and buid actionbarsherlock, remove the actionbarsherlock library in siphome, clean and build it, you will have errors (obvious) then add actionbarsherlock library and rebuild siphome.

Once done, make the same thing for your project, remove siphome library, clean an build, add siphome again and rebuild.

Worked for me.